# Why during run time Js get messy

Tags: javascript, buildingblocks

I was doing a function to toggle up between `CSS` classes for an `HTML` element using a *clases* object with 2 properties, *active* and *non-active* and a global variable *count* to keep track the run times. I realize some strange JS behavior:

Here it goes fine, in the console output I get the toggle effect

```js
function toogleClases() {
    if(count%2==0){
        return clases.active;
    }
    else{
        return clases.non_active;
    }
}
for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    console.log(toogleClases());
    count++;
}
```

but if I insert the `count++` into the toogle function itself ( what i think is more practical)

```js
function toogleClases() {
    if(count%2==0){
        return clases.active;
    }
    else{
        return clases.non_active;
    }
    count++;
}

for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    console.log(toogleClases());
}
```

i get always the same value on the console '10 times : active' , i will love to know why this happen, i suspect that it is a weird Js part

Comment: Where do you define `count`?

Answer (score 0):

Your function return output before update the count variable. anything after return statement does not trigger so your `count` value is always `0`. you need to update `count++` before return the output.

```js
var count = 0;
function toogleClases() {
   
    let status = false;
    if(count%2 == 0){
        status = true;
    } 
    
    count++;
    return status ? 'active' : 'non active';
    //replace 'active' with clases.active and 'non active' with  clases.non_active
   
}

for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    console.log(toogleClases());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling `count++` after `toogleClases()` returns, `count++` will never be reached. Try this instead:

```
function toogleClases() {
    if(count%2==0){
        count++;
        return clases.active;
    }
    else{
        count++;
        return clases.non_active;
    }

}

for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    console.log(toogleClases());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a counter you can pass i as parameter:

```
 function toogleClases(count) {
    if(count%2==0){
        return clases.active;
    }
    else{
        return clases.non_active;
    }

}

for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    console.log(toogleClases(i));
}
```